# Creating a branch for a project that has common shared files with another projects

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

My team is about to give Mercurial and its branching features a try (right now we are on Subversion but it is being used mainly as a code storage rather than a full version control system with branching, etc). So here is a problem: I am developing a set of DLLs, each library implementation sits in its own folder. And I have one place ("Common" folder) that contains interface units for these libraries as well as common units from other team mates.

It looks like this:

```
    \Source  
        \MyLibrary1  
        \MyLibrary2  
        \MyLibrary3  
    \Common  
        MyLibrary1_Intf.h  
        MyLibrary2_Intf.h  
        MyLibrary3_Intf.h
```

What should I do when I want to create a branch for MyLibrary3? Ok, I am creating a branch for MyLibrary3 but what about MyLibrary3_Intf.h? Should I create a branch for \Common as well? I should mention that it is supposed that each project (library) sits in its own repository. As well as Common files. I dont like the idea to create one repository for all source tree because there are A LOT OF libraries. Question is: how do u deal with such situation?

Comment: Do you use file-based externals in SVN (for `Common` sources)?

Comment: @LazyBadger Yep, this `Common` is the svn:external

Comment: directory-based of file-based? Do you want to maintain this separation per repos in Mercurial?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should give subrepositories a try:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

Comment: Love that first line of the documentation, "This is considered a feature of last resort."  But is the right way.  +1

Comment: @djc I was thinking of using subrepos, yes. The only thing that stops me is that "feature of last resort" thing and my guess is that I am not the only one who's sort of afraid using these last resort features.

Comment: @segatron - "last resort" only for some mercurials and not final and undisputable solution. And yes, it has some drawbacks, avoided (at least tried to) in Guestrepo extension

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to "publish" your libraries independently, you can use separate repositories. Otherwise, it is better off to use ONE repo to save yourself a lot of repo-management and library-synchronization troubles.

With 1 repo, you can use real branches to achieve clean revision histories for individual libraries (if that's a goal). The branching model can look like the following:

```
develop    
main branch  ----------o--o---------o---o--
                      /  /|        /   /
lib1 branch  --o--o--o----+-o---------o----
                       /  |      / 
lib2 branch  --o------o---+--o-------------
                          |    /    
lib3 branch  -o----o------+---o------o-----
                          ^
                         sync
```

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to give 1 repository model a try (as I explained in the latter answer)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to know and understand at least *some* fundamental differences between Subversion and Mercurial (it's **not** about CVCS vs DVCS)

- In Subversion you can (and *have* for the most of layouts really) branch **any part** of subtree, if you want. In Mercurial you branch the whole repository
- In Subversion svn:externals can refer to directory or single file inside directory, in Mercurial (sub|guest)repos can link only the whole external repository (at some state) - i.e you will not be able to link (easy, tricks still possible) in MyLibrary1 repository MyLibrary1_Intf.h **file**, only repository (separate for MyLibrary1_Intf.h or shared with all Common)

**About your problem**:

When (if) MyLibrary* and Common are independent repositories, linked as super- and subrepo, branching in MyLibrary* doesn't affect Common (you always linked in some state /changeset/ of subrepo /which can be in the same or different branches for different branches in superrepo/ in superrepo's .hgsubstate), thus - it's your free choice how to change *.h files according to requirements of changes in library's branch

**PS**: The promised trick with one Common repo for all *.h, but single needed file in subrepo

Subrepo definition allow using any legal for URLs specifications, one of these is `repository#cset-id`, where changeset-id may be any applicable id (and branchname also). So, if you'll create from default branch (which contain all files) separate named branches for every MyLibrary and delete in every this branch files, unrelated to specific library, define suprepo with branch-id, superrepo will know about only file(s) in this branch

Comment: @Badger Thank you for you answer! After reading a bunch of articles across the Web and discussing with my team mates I decided to go with 1 repository. I have come across this brilliant article [link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) - very much liked the described scenario and I will implement something similar here just simplier (for starters). Yes, 1 repository will add quite a bit of overhead while branching/cloning but I think it is the most painless way for starters. And since all of my team mates are on the same local area network speed is not significant.

Comment: You don't have to implement git-flow yourself. Consider/try [hgflow](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home), which implements a generalized branching model and is even more powerful than git-flow.

Comment: @schrodinger'scat - thx for reminding hgflow, but main trouble of OP is not "reinvent the wheel", but adopt *his* svn:externals usage-style to Mercurial *-repo (as I understood problem)

Comment: @schrodinger'scat Oh, many thanks for mentioning hgflow, I will check it out